# Who discovered the winding number?

Tags: reference-request

I would guess it was well known by the time of Cauchy. But are there earlier references to it?

Comment: Joshua 6:3-4?  "You shall march around the city, all the men of war going around the city once... and on the seventh day you shall march around the city seven times..."

Comment: @Robert: Does the next line say "And if you reverse orientation on every other day then in fact you shall only march around the city once..."?

Comment: No. If you reverse orientation on every successive day, you will have marched around the city seven times. The instructions were to march around the city once on each of days 1-6 and then seven times on the seventh day.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Grünbaum and Shephard](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1990-322-01/S0002-9947-1990-1024774-2/S0002-9947-1990-1024774-2.pdf)  suggest that the winding numbers (for closed polygons) have been discussed in the literature at least since 1769.

See
A.L.F.  Meister,  *Generalia de genesi figurarum  planarum et  inde pendentibus earum ajfectionibus*,  Novi Comm. Soc.  Reg.  Scient.  Gotting.  1 (1769/70),  pp.  144-180.